# kubernetes port-forward sticks on [::1]:8080->8080

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I'm trying to forward port 8080 for my nginx ingress controller for Kubernetes. I'm running the command:

```
kubectl -n nginx-ingress port-forward nginx-ingress-768dfsssd5bf-v23ja 8080:8080 --request-timeout 0
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 8080
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 8080
```

It just hangs on `::1` forever. Is there a log somewhere I can view to see why its hanging?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's expected  behaviour - `kubectl port-forward` is not getting [daemonized by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863164/kubernetes-prompt-freezes-at-port-forward-command/48866118#48866118). From the [official Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/#forward-a-local-port-to-a-port-on-the-pod):

> **Note:**  `kubectl port-forward` does not return. To continue with the exercises, you will need to open another terminal.

The all logs will be shown in `kubectl port-forward` command output:

```
user@shell:~$ kubectl port-forward deployment/nginx-deployment 80:80
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:80 -> 80
```

[Including errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53799600/kubernetes-port-forwarding-connection-refused):

```
Handling connection for 88
Handling connection for 88
E1214 01:25:48.704335   51463 portforward.go:331] an error occurred forwarding 88 -> 82: error forwarding port 82 to pod a017a46573bbc065902b600f0767d3b366c5dcfe6782c3c31d2652b4c2b76941, uid : exit status 1: 2018/12/14 08:25:48 socat[19382] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:82, 16): Connection refused
```

If you don't have any logs that means you didn't make an attempt to connect or you specified a wrong address / port.

As earlier mentioned, you can open a new terminal window, you can also run `kubectl port-forward` [in the background](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-run-linux-commands-in-background/) by adding `&` at the end of the command:

```
kubectl -n nginx-ingress port-forward nginx-ingress-768dfsssd5bf-v23ja 8080:8080 --request-timeout 0 &
```

If you want to run `kubectl port-forward` in background and save all logs to the file you can use [`nohup` command](https://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/) + `&` at the end:

```
nohup kubectl -n nginx-ingress port-forward nginx-ingress-768dfsssd5bf-v23ja 8080:8080 --request-timeout 0 &
```